# How to position text on background image responsively?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create links (about 4 text links, one pop up menu link) going up the walkway to the treehouse. Obviously, I want the links to always appear in these same spots, no matter how big or small the screen size. Help please?

Image:
http://www.mostbeautifulthings.net/amazing-tree-house-designs/
***the 6th one down***

(I'm new to stack overflow, so it wouldn't let me directly post the picture)

Edit by Ram: I guess this is the one
[image]

Comment: Some code would be nice so we can see what is wrong (or what needs to be adjusted). However setting width (or height) to a % might fix it.

Comment: If you relatively position your containing div, then absolutely position the text element (h1), you can use top left right bottom positioning to put the text where you like relative to the containing div.

Comment: can you explain your use case here? this is an unusual way to place links.

Comment: You can check this link may be it solves your problem. http://www.minimit.com/demos/fullscreen-backgrounds-with-centered-content